# Div background-color not showing up?

Tags: html, css

So I found a nice codepen and started playing with it:

http://codepen.io/georgehastings/full/xgwxgo

The problem is that I can't seem to make the black `background-color` of my `div` appear so that the glowing stays BEHIND the `div` and not ontop of it.

My current situation:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgavRb

What have I done wrong ?

I am looking for an effect similar to this:

http://assets.razerzone.com/eeimages/products/25594/firefly-cloth-tech-bg.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use another element instead of the `:after`, see this as an example:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.homeTitle {
  z-index: 14;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #252B37;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 7vh;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: gamers;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /*  animation: textColor 10s ease infinite;*/
}
.homeTitleBack {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  left: 40%;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 47%;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5vw);
  -moz-filter: blur(5vw);
  -ms-filter: blur(5vw);
  filter: blur(5vw);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  animation: animateGlowing 10s ease infinite;
}
@keyframes animateGlowing {
  0% {
    background: #FF0000;
  }
  33% {
    background: #7e0fff;
  }
  66% {
    background: #0053FF;
  }
  100% {
    background: #FF0000;
  }
}
@keyframes textColor {
  0% {
    color: #7e0fff;
  }
  50% {
    color: #0fffc1;
  }
  100% {
    color: #7e0fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="homeTitleBack"></div>
<div class="homeTitle">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` of a child element will always be higher than the `z-index` of its parent, despite what you set in the CSS.

You can use a `:before` pseudo element in front of the `:after` pseudo element however.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgavRb  Is this what you suggested ? The glow disappeared :/

Comment: You can only target one pseudo element at a time. `.homeTitle:before` for instance. Then make it a black element COVERING the glow `:after` element. Like a black card in front of the glow.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one div for the effect and another for the black box

```
<div class ="homeTitle">
  <div style="background: black">Test</div>
</div>
```